Header narrower than container isn't centered with auto margins
I'm trying to have centred rows, one for the title, one for the description, and one for the content. In the content, paragraph and header widths are limited to 30ch, but images can span the full container width. It looks like this:


#content p,
#content h2 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 30ch;
}

#content img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
<div class="align-items-center d-flex flex-column">
  <div id="title">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="description">
    <p class="lead">Description</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>This article offers a sample of basic Markdown syntax that can be used in Hugo content files, also it shows whether basic HTML elements are decorated with CSS in a Hugo theme.</p>
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>This article offers a sample of basic Markdown syntax that can be used in Hugo content files, also it shows whether basic HTML elements are decorated with CSS in a Hugo theme.</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Bar</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>This article offers a sample of basic Markdown syntax that can be used in Hugo content files, also it shows whether basic HTML elements are decorated with CSS in a Hugo theme.</p>
    <img src="https://studentfutures.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/testing-1.jpg">
    <p>This article offers a sample of basic Markdown syntax that can be used in Hugo content files, also it shows whether basic HTML elements are decorated with CSS in a Hugo theme.</p>
  </div>
</div>



Most of it works:

However, the content header isn't constrained to a width of 30ch (see "Foo" above).
I noticed the same for tables (see "Bar" above).
How do I get headers and tables to obey the 30ch width limit?
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0hv46qLs/1/

Foo is constrained to 30ch, but the font size is bigger, so 30ch for that element is bigger. You're better off using rem if you want everything to be the same width.

You may want to look at W3.org's documentation on "font-relative lengths," if you really want to use ch (character width of the font's zero character), I'd echo ralph.m's sentiment and suggest using the rch unit.

Thank you very much! That was it. Strange that it uses the font size inside the element instead of its container.

The issue was using the ch unit. Switching to rem units fixed it. Apparently, max-width uses the ch size from inside the element, not its container.
